# Ruta absoluta para imagenes java jsp

Tags: java, jsp, imagen, rutas

Estoy trabajando en java jsp y estoy realizando la parte donde un usuario agrega su foto de perfil y tengo una duda sobre esto.
Con documentos para subirlos al servidor lo hago de esta manera con la ruta absoluta,

```
public static String rutaDocumento(String nombredocumento) {
        File file = new File(nombredocumento);
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Con imágenes lo hago poniendo la ruta del computador desde disco local C hasta una carpeta dentro del proyecto Ejemplo:

```
 public static String rutaFotoperfil(String nombrefoto) {
        File filefotos = new File("Fotos");
        System.out.println(filefotos.getAbsolutePath());

        return "C:\\Users\\Angela\\Documents\\Proyecto\\web\\Documentos\\Fotosperfil\\" + nombrefoto;
    }
```

Así lo hago y funciona bien , mi problema es al desplegar el proyecto a un servidor web ya que esa ruta de fotos no seria la misma para el servidor web y no se como se realizaría esta parte para subir las fotos al servidor pero ya que el tome la propia ruta de donde debe subir la imagen por que la foto la carga en el html de carpetas `src="Documentos/Fotosperfil/${usuario.getImagenPerfil()}"` así esta actualmente.
Entonces mi pregunta estaría basada en como puedo subir una imagen a esa misma carpeta pero que tome la ruta del servidor web al desplegar sin necesidad de decir que en el disco C: como cuando una agrega una imagen de una carpeta con `CSS` o como me lo recomendarían por este medio.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde la pagina JSP podes acceder al contexto del directorio Web.
Ejemplo de pagina JSP:

```
<%
File f = new File(application.getRealPath("/"));
String nombreArchivo = "archivo.jpg";
String ruta = f.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Documentos" + File.separator + "Fotosperfil" + File.separator + nombreArchivo;
%>
```

Comment: de esa manera me toma tan bien la ruta de mi pc , digamos que me sirve pero es que cuando despliegue mi .war generaria error porque necesito hacer que llegue a una ruta que pueda acceder desde el localhot para poner la ruta http en el html de la imagen y asi acceda a esa ruta , si pongo que valla a --> C:\Payara\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot  <-- y guarde la foto hay y en el html en la imagen pongo  src="http://localhost:8080/Foto.png" si me va servir 100% pero cuando desplieque el .war  no funcionara porque le estoy dando la ruta quemada de mi pc

Comment: Hola Angelica para mostrar imagenes o videos en una web debes usar la ruta relativa no la absoluta.

Comment: Hola Angelica para mostrar imagenes o videos en una web debes usar la ruta relativa no la absoluta. Si tenes una imagen en la raiz del directorio web ejemplo: C:\Payara\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot\imagen.jpg utilizas src="imagen.jpg".
Si tenes una imagen en un directorio adicional ejemplo: C:\Payara\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot\Carpeta1\imagen.jpg usas src="Carpeta1/imagen.jpg".
Nunca uses src de rutas absolutas, porque solo va a funcionar en tu pc porque tienen acceso directo al disco.
Disculpa por el mareo, pense que el JSP que necesitabas accedia al archivo para enviar  el bin

Comment: Hola toto, ya lo intente como dices mira.
Las fotos las hice llegar aca C:\Payara\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot  , las fotos estan en esa carpeta docroot y el imagen lo deje asi -->   <img class="card w-100 p-3 h-75 d-inline-block" src="Foto.png"> , pero no funciona

Comment: Oye ya en el img me falto dejar src="\Foto.png" muchas garcias por la ayuda